# Read XAML with power shell

Tags: powershell, xaml

I have an XAML file below which is created by Visual Studio, I'm unable to read the nodes using powershell using name attribute.

I have tried below command to read from $XAML

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')
$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml) 
$Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )

$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | ForEach-Object {Set-Variable -Name ($.Name) -Value $Form.FindName($_.Name)}
```

Above mentioned commands were working perfectly with another XAML file, now I don't get any values from the below pasted XAML,
difference with this XAML I could see is the addition of grid. however I need to use below XAML. any help is appreciated.

my XAML file available Here https://gist.github.com/pramodtvm/c5f5d4d262c2d0ab72d502d1d526c309

Comment: Does `$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]")` return *anything*?

Comment: nope it does not return anything, but $xaml.Window.Grid shows  button,labels,grid and textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, seems like some namespace stuff, can you just use this:

```
$XAML.GetElementsByTagName("*")|? { $Form.FindName($_.Name) }|% { Set-Variable -Name $_.Name -Value $_ }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here I am pasting complete working code so that it help some one else with Power shell and WPF

`Add-Type -AssemblyName presentationframework,presentationcore`

parse your Visual Studio Created XAML here below
`$Inputxaml = @' Replace your XAML file '@`

Run Below clean up step as few of the strings created by VS are not accepted by powershell
`$CleanUp = $Inputxaml -replace 'mc:Ignorable="d"','' -replace "x:N",'N' -replace 'x:Class=".*?"','' -replace 'd:DesignHeight="\d*?"','' -replace 'd:DesignWidth="\d*?"',''`
`[xml]$xaml = $CleanUp`

`$wpf =@{}`
`$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)`
`$Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )`

Run through XAML nodes and create name Nodes
`$namenodes = $XAML.SelectNodes("//*[@*[contains(translate(name(.),'n','N'),'Name')]]")
$namenodes | ForEach-Object{
        $wpf.add($_.Name,$Form.FindName($_.Name))}`

Create Event functions
`$wpf.buttonnew.add_Click({
    })`

Show GUI
`$Form.ShowDialog() | out-null`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of setting variables to the named controls found in the xaml file.

It includes an example of disabling them too if need be. I found this useful to disable the controls while a directory picker showed up first.

```
$formNamedNodes = $xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@*[contains(translate(name(.),'n','N'),'Name')]]") | Sort
$formNamedNodes | ForEach-Object {

  # Write-Host $_.Name # Prints out the list of controls

  # Set the variable names to the same as that of the controls.
  Set-Variable -Name $_.Name -Value $Form.FindName($_.Name)

  # Here are the controls that I want to disable.
  If ($_.Name -eq "btnDonate" -or $_.Name -eq "btnCancelClose") {
   $Form.FindName($_.Name).IsEnabled = $true
 }
 else {
   $Form.FindName($_.Name).IsEnabled = $false
 }

}
```